# Optimize permutations search loop (can't use itertools) that is extremely slow. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, optimization, permutation, python-itertools, pypy

This is a game where you have 12 cards and you pick you until you choose 3 from the same group. I am attempting to find the probability of choosing each group. The script that I have created works, but it is extremely slow. My coworker created a similar script in R without the functions and his script takes 1/100th the time that mine takes. I am just trying to figure out why. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

weight = pd.read_excel('V01Weights.xlsx')
```

Weight looks like the following:

```
Symb    Weight
Grand   170000
Grand   170000
Grand   105
Major   170000
Major   170000
Major   215
Minor   150000
Minor   150000
Minor   12000
Bonus   105000
Bonus   105000
Bonus   105000
```

Max Picks represents the total number of different "cards". Total Picks represents the max number of user choices. This is because after 8 choices, you are guaranteed to have 2 of each type so on the 9th pick, you are guaranteed to have 3 matching.

```
TotalPicks = 9
MaxPicks = 12
```

This should have been named PickedProbabilities.

```
Picks = {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0}
```

This is my simple version of the timeit class because I don't like the timeit class

```
def Time_It(function):
    start =datetime.now()

    x = function()

    finish = datetime.now()

    TotalTime = finish - start

    Minutes = int(TotalTime.seconds/60)
    Seconds = TotalTime.seconds % 60


    print('It took ' + str(Minutes) + ' minutes and ' + str(Seconds) + ' seconds')

    return(x)
```

Given x(my picks in order) I find the probability. These picks are done without replacement

```
def Get_Prob(x,weight):
    prob = 1
    weights = weight.iloc[:,1]

    for index in x:
        num = weights[index]
        denom = sum(weights)

        prob *= num/denom
        weights.drop(index, inplace = True)
        # print(weights)

    return(prob)
```

This is used to determine if there are duplicates in my loop because that is not allowed

```
def Is_Allowed(x):
    return(len(x) == len(set(x)))
```

This determines if a win is present in all of the cards present thus far.

```
def Is_Win(x):
    global Picks

    WinTypes = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]

    IsWin = False

    for index,item in enumerate(WinTypes):
        # print(index)
        if set(item).issubset(set(x)):
            IsWin = True
            Picks[index] += Get_Prob(x,weight)
            # print(Picks[index])
            print(sum(Picks.values()))
            break

    return(IsWin)
```

This is my main function that cycles through all of the cards. I attempted to do this using recursion but I eventually gave up. I can't use itertools to create all of the permutations because for example [0,1,2,3,4] will be created by itertools but this is not possible because once you get 3 matching, the game ends.

```
def Cycle():

    for a in range(MaxPicks):
        x = [a]

        for b in range(MaxPicks):
            x = [a,b]

            if Is_Allowed(x):
                for c in range(MaxPicks):
                    x = [a,b,c]
                    if Is_Allowed(x):                    
                        if Is_Win(x):
                            # print(x)
                            continue
                        for d in range(MaxPicks):
                            x = [a,b,c,d]
                            if Is_Allowed(x):
                                if Is_Win(x):
                                    # print(x)
                                    continue
                            for e in range(MaxPicks):
                                x = [a,b,c,d,e]
                                if Is_Allowed(x):
                                    if Is_Win(x):
                                        continue
                                for f in range(MaxPicks):
                                    x = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
                                    if Is_Allowed(x):
                                        if Is_Win(x):
                                            continue
                                    for g in range(MaxPicks):
                                        x = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
                                        if Is_Allowed(x):
                                            if Is_Win(x):
                                                continue
                                        for h in range(MaxPicks):
                                            x = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
                                            if Is_Allowed(x):
                                                if Is_Win(x):
                                                    continue
                                            for i in range(MaxPicks):
                                                if Is_Allowed(x):
                                                    if Is_Win(x):
                                                        continue
```

Calls the main function

```
x = Time_It(Cycle)
print(x)
```

writes the probabilities to a text file

```
with open('result.txt','w') as file:
    # file.write(pickle.dumps(x))
    for item in x:
        file.write(str(item) + ',' + str(x[item]) + '\n')
```

Comment: The problem here is that you're trying to loop through all permutations. Don't do that; find a smarter way to compute the probabilities.

Comment: If you have any ideas, I would definitely take the suggestions. In this particular case, I don't think there is any easy way around it.

Comment: You should heed the advice of user2357112: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem to get you started.

Comment: Btw: you could replace individual weights through the average weight of the corresponding group. This would simplify your task a little.

Comment: ead: do you have any specific suggestions on how I could avoid using all of the loops because I have attempted to find a different solution in the past with no success. I need exact probability so I don't think that I can replace the individual weights with the average weight unless I am misunderstanding what you are saying. I am thinking of computing the cumulative prob in each loop so that it doesn't have to continually recalculate the first few probs for example so thank you for that idea.

Comment: Because the probability of picking a card is equal for every card, you don't have to know exactly which card from a group was picked - just use the average weight. If you don't believe me - just replace the weights with the average weight of the group and see, that the results stay unchanged. After having having done that you will have a more complex version of the urn problem, that means you will need to check less than `4^3` states compared to '12!' with your approach.

Comment: now I understand. I included the weights in the code that I posted but it seems that I didn't make that very clear. There are 3 each of grand, major, minor, and bonus, all of which have different weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this time I hope I got your problem right:)

There are two insights (I guess you have them, just for the sake of the completeness) needed in order to speed up your program *algorithmically*:

1. The probabilities for the sequence `(card_1, card_2)`  and `(card_2, card_1)`  are not equal, so we cannot use the results from the urn problem, and it looks like we need to try out all permutations.
2. However, given a set of cards we picked so far, we don't really need the information in which sequence they where picked - it is all the same for the future course of the game. So it is enough to use dynamic programming and calculate the probabilities for every subset to be traversed during the game (thus we need to check `2^N` instead of `N!` states).

For a set of picked cards `set` the probability to pick a card `i`  in the next turn is:

```
 norm:=sum Wi for i in set 
 P(i|set)=Wi/norm if i not in set else 0.0
```

The recursion for calculating `P(set)` - the probability that a set of picked card occured during the game is:

```
set_without_i:=set/{i}
P(set)=sum P(set_without_i)*P(i|set_without_i) for i in set
```

However this should be done only for `set_without_i` for which the game not ended yet, i.e. no group has 3 cards picked.

This can be done by means of recursion+memoization or, as my version does, by using bottom-up dynamic programming. It also uses binary representation of integers for representations of sets and (most important part!) returns the result almost instantly `[('Grand', 0.0014104762718021384), ('Major', 0.0028878988709489244), ('Minor', 0.15321793072867956), ('Bonus', 0.84248369412856905)]`:

```
#calculates probability to end the game with 3 cards of a type


N=12

#set representation int->list
def decode_set(encoded):
    decoded=[False]*N
    for i in xrange(N):
        if encoded&(1<<i):
            decoded[i]=True
    return decoded

weights = [170000, 170000, 105, 170000, 170000, 215, 150000, 150000, 12000, 105000, 105000, 105000]     
def get_probs(decoded_set):
    denom=float(sum((w for w,is_taken in zip(weights, decoded_set) if not is_taken)))
    return [w/denom if not is_taken else 0.0 for w,is_taken in zip(weights, decoded_set)]

def end_group(encoded_set):
    for i in xrange(4):
       whole_group =  7<<(3*i) #7=..000111, 56=00111000 and so on
       if (encoded_set & whole_group)==whole_group:
           return i
    return None


#MAIN: dynamic program:

MAX=(1<<N)#max possible set is 1<<N-1
probs=[0.0]*MAX

#we always start with the empty set:
probs[0]=1.0    
#building bottom-up
for current_set in xrange(MAX):
    if end_group(current_set) is None:  #game not ended yet!
       decoded_set=decode_set(current_set)
       trans_probs=get_probs(decoded_set)
       for i, is_set in enumerate(decoded_set):
           if not is_set:
              new_set=current_set | (1<<i) 
              probs[new_set]+=probs[current_set]*trans_probs[i]

#filtering wins:
group_probs=[0.0]*4
for current_set in xrange(MAX):
   group_won=end_group(current_set)
   if group_won is not None:
      group_probs[group_won]+=probs[current_set]


print zip(["Grand", "Major", "Minor", "Bonus"], group_probs)
```

---

**Some explanation of the "tricks" used in code:**

A pretty standard trick is to use integer's binary representation to encode a set. Let's say we have objects `[a,b,c]`, so we could represent the set `{b,c}` as `110`, which would mean `a` (first in the list corresponds to `0`- the lowest digit) - not in the set, `b(1)` in the set, `c(1)` in the set. However, `110` read as integer it is `6`.

The current_set - for loop simulates the game and best understood while playing. Let's play with two cards `[a,b]` with weights `[2,1]`.

We start the game with an empty set, `0` as integer, so the probability vector (given set, its binary representation and as integer mapped onto probability):

```
  probs=[{}=00=0->1.0,  01={a}=1->0.0, {b}=10=2->0.0, {a,b}=11=3->0.0]
```

We process the `current_set=0`, there are two possibilities 66% to take card `a` and 33% to take card`b`, so the probabilities become after the processing:

```
 probs=[{}=00=0->1.0,  01={a}=1->0.66, {b}=10=2->0.33, {a,b}=11=3->0.0]
```

Now we process the `current_set=1={a}` the only possibility is to take `b` so we will end with set `{a,b}`. So we need to update its (`3={a,b}`) probability via our formula and we get:

```
 probs=[{}=00=0->1.0,  01={a}=1->0.66, {b}=10=2->0.33, {a,b}=11=3->0.66]
```

In the next step we process `2`, and given set {b} the only possibility is to pick card `a`, so probability of set `{a,b}` needs to be updated again

```
probs=[{}=00=0->1.0,  01={a}=1->0.66, {b}=10=2->0.33, {a,b}=11=3->1.0]
```

We can get to `{a,b}` on two different paths - this could be seen in our algorithm. The probability to go through set `{a,b}` at some point in our game is obviously `1.0`.

Another important thing: all paths that leads to `{a,b}` are taken care of before we process this set (it would be the next step).

Comment: still working on understanding the entirety of your solution, but you can explain why, or point me to where i can find out, why you used binary for this problem. For example ,1<<N-1. You create a list of 4096(2^12) zeroes for the starting probability but why? I can only assume that this is why your script can run so quickly but I have no idea.
Thanks for your awesome response and I'm glad you are enjoying yourself(based on another comment). I'm definitely learning a lot.

Comment: I have posted your code on my [github page](https://github.com/Christhomas17/12CardsChoose3UsingBinaryRepresentation/blob/master/README.md), giving you full credit. I did this only so that I can share with anyone else, who like me, was confused and in awe of your code. Please let me know if you would like me to take it down or if you have any other comments.

Comment: @ChrisThomas you are welcome. Actually this is nothing special and pretty standard tricks I learned on stackoverflow and on internet over the years

Comment: What you consider standard tricks, I consider voodoo. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> My coworker created a similar script in R without the functions and his script takes 1/100th the time that mine takes.

Two easy optimizations:

1) In-line the function calls like `Is_Allowed()` because Python have a lot of function call overhead (such as creating a new stackframe and argument tuples).

2) Run the code in using [pypy](http://pypy.org/) which is really good at optimizing functions like this one.

Comment: The whole reason that I used the functions was the readability and so that I didn't need to copy and paste those functions over and over. It seems almost, 'unpythonic' to copy and paste them over and over. I'm not implying that you are wrong, because I definitely feel that this is the reason behind the long running time, but it seems curious.Do you have any links to where I could read about the 'call overhead' that you mentioned above to understand this better?
I will definitely take a look into pypy because I often using loops so that could definitely be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisThomas We all like functions for readability, so we really miss them after optimizing ;-)   You don't need to read about call overhead, just run some timings, perhaps ``python -m timeit -s 'x=10' 'x+3'`` versus ``python -m timeit -s 'x=10' -s 'add3 = lambda x: x+3' 'add3(x)'``.

Comment: I definitely need to start timing the smaller portions of my code so that I can implement them better. Thanks. I'm probably going to rewrite it without the functions and see how that goes.Thanks for taking the time to read and answer.

Comment: I think there is a lot to win through  switching to pypy and through improving the code, but even more by improving the algorithm, see for example my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I misunderstood the original problem, the here presented solution is for the following problem:

> Given 4 groups with 3 different cards with a different score for every card, we pick up cards as long as we don't have picked 3 cards from the same group. What is the expected score(sum of scores of picked cards) in the end of the game.

I leave the solution as it is, because it was such a joy to work it out after so many probability-theory-less years and I just cannot delete it:)

See my other answer for handling of the original problem

---

There are two possibilities to improve the performance: making the code faster (and before starting this, one should profile in order to know which part of the program should be optimized, otherwise the time is spent optimizing things that don't count) or improving the algorithm. I propose to do the second.

Ok, this problem seems to be more complex as at the first site. Let's start with some observations.

---

**All you need to know is the expected number of the picked cards at the end of the game:**

If `Pi` is the probability that the card `i` is picked somewhere during the game, then we are looking for the expected value of the score `E(Score)=P1*W1+P2*W2+...Pn*Wn`. However, if we look at the cards of a group, we can state that because of the symmetry the probabilities for the cards of this group are the same, e.g. `P1=P2=P3=:Pgrand` in your case. Thus our expectation can be calculated:

```
E(Score)=3*Pgrand*(W1+W2+W3)/3+...+3*Pbonus*(W10+W11+W12)/3
```

We call `averageWgrand:=(W1+W2+W3)/3` and note that `E(#grand)=3*Pgrand` - the expected number of picked grand card at the  end of the game. With this our formula becomes:

```
E(Score)=E(#grand)*averageWgrand+...+E(#bonus)*averageWbonus
```

In your example we can go even further: The number of cards in every group is equal, so because of the symmetry we can claim: `E(#grand)=E(#minor)=E(#major)=E(#grand)=:(E#group)`. For the sake of simplicity, in the following we consider only this special case (but the outlined solution could be extended also to the general case). This lead to the following simplification:

```
E(Score)=4*E(#group)(averageWgrand+...+averageWbonus)/4
```

We call `averageW:=(averageWgrand+...+averageWbonus)/4` and note that `E(#cards)=4*E(#grand)` is the expected number of picked card at the  end of the game.

Thus, `E(Score)=E(#cards)*averageW`, so our task is reduced to calculating the expected value of the number of cards at the end of the game:

```
 E(#cards)=P(1)*1+P(2)*2+...P(n)*n
```

where `P(i)` denotes the probability, that the game ends with exact `i` cards. The probabilities `P(1)`,`P(2)` and `P(k)`, `k>9` are easy to see - they are `0`.

---

**Calculation of the probability of ending the game with `i` picked cards -`P(i)`:**

Let's play a slightly different game: we pick exactly `i` cards and win if and only if:

1. There is exactly one group with 3 cards picked. We call this group `full_group`.
2. The last picked (i-th) card was from the `full_group`.

It is easy to see, that the probability to win this game `P(win)` is exactly the probability we are looking for - `P(i)`. Once again we can use the symmetry, because all groups are equal (`P(win, full=grand)` means the probability that we what and that the `full_group=grand`):

```
 P(win)=P(win, grand)+P(win, minor)+P(win, major)+P(win, bonus)
       =4*P(win, grand)
```

`P(win, grand)` is the probability that:

1. after picking `i-1` cards the number of picked grand cards is 2, i.e. `#grand=2' and
2. after picking `i-1` cards, for every group the number of picked cards is less than 3 and
3. we pick a grand-card in the last round. Given the first two constraints hold, this (conditional) probability is `1/(n-i+1)` (there are `n-i+1` cards left and only one of them is "right").

From the urn problem we know the probability for

```
P(#grand=u, #minor=x, #major=y, #bonus=z) = binom(3,u)*binom(3,x)*binom(3,y)*binom(3,z)/binom(12, u+x+y+z)
```

with `binom(n,k)=n!/k!/(n-k)!`. Thus `P(win, grand)` can be calculated as:

```
P(win, grand) = 1/(n-i+1)*sum P(#grand=2, #minor=x, #major=y, #bonus=z)
               where x<=2, y<=2, z<=2 and 2+x+y+z=i-1
```

---

**And now the code:**

```
import math

def binom(n,k):
  return math.factorial(n)//math.factorial(k)//math.factorial(n-k)

#expected number of cards:

n=12 #there are 12 cards
probs=[0]*n
for minor in xrange(3):
  for major in xrange(3):
     for bonus in xrange(3):
         i = 3 + minor +major +bonus 
         P_urn = binom(3,2)*binom(3,minor)*binom(3,major)*binom(3,bonus)/float(binom(n, n-i+1))
         P_right_last_card = 1.0/(n-i+1)
         probs[i]+=4*P_urn*P_right_last_card #factor 4 from symmetry


print "Expected number of cards:", sum((prob*card_cnt for card_cnt, prob in enumerate(probs)))
```

As result I get `6.94285714286` as the expected number of cards in the end of the game. And very fast - almost instantly. Not sure whether it is right though...

---

**Conclusion:**

Obviously, if you like to handle a more general case (more groups, number cards in a group different) you have to extend the code (recursion, memoization of `binom`) and the theory.

But the most crucial part: with this approach you (almost) don't care in which order the cards were picked - and thus the number of states you have to inspect is down by factor of `(k-1)!` where `k` is the maximal possible number of cards in the end of the game. In your example `k=9` and thus the approach is faster by factor `40000` (I don't even consider the speed-up from the exploited symmetry, because it might not be possible in general case).

Comment: I need to know the specific probability of picking 3 cards from each group before 3 from a different group are picked. For example, if I choose Grand, Grand, Grand(Grand,Major,Grand,Grand is similar) then the game is over and no more cards are chosen. Because of this, I don't believe that I can use expected value. I could only use that if I was trying to find, as you said, the expected number of cards. I'm sorry if I am still misunderstanding what you are trying to accomplish, but I don't believe that this can be reduced to an expected value problem. Thanks again for your attempt though.

Comment: @ChrisThomas So what result do you get with your algorithm?

Comment: PGrand  = 0.001410476
PMajor  = 0.002887899
PMinor = 0.153217931
PMini  = 0.842483694
sum   = 1
sorry for the formatting.

Comment: @ChrisThomas Oh now I see my misunderstanding, I read your question some time ago and solved a totally different problem... sorry for trouble

Comment: I truly appreciate the effort. Thanks.